# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in line 68

Tags: php, moodle

I am very new to PHP and have no idea why this is happening, I have looked at other online items, however I just cannot seem to see why I am getting this error.

```
if (get_home_page() != HOMEPAGE_SITE) {
// Redirect logged-in users to My Moodle overview if required.
$redirect = optional_param('redirect', 1, PARAM_BOOL);
if (optional_param('setdefaulthome', false, PARAM_BOOL)) {
    set_user_preference('user_home_page_preference', HOMEPAGE_SITE);
} else if (!empty($CFG->defaulthomepage) && ($CFG->defaulthomepage == HOMEPAGE_MY) && $redirect === 1) {
    redirect($CFG->wwwroot .'/my/');
} else if (!empty($CFG->defaulthomepage) && ($CFG->defaulthomepage == HOMEPAGE_USER)) {
    $frontpagenode = $PAGE->settingsnav->find('frontpage', null);
    if ($frontpagenode) {
        $frontpagenode->add(
            get_string('makethismyhome'),
            new moodle_url('/', array('setdefaulthome' => true)),
            navigation_node::TYPE_SETTING);
    } else {
        $frontpagenode = $PAGE->settingsnav->add(get_string('frontpagesettings'), null, navigation_node::TYPE_SETTING, null);
        $frontpagenode->force_open();
        $frontpagenode->add(get_string('makethismyhome'),
            new moodle_url('/', array('setdefaulthome' => true)),
            navigation_node::TYPE_SETTING);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That is not that file or is incomplete. Which line is 68?

Comment: Line 68 is  $redirect = optional_param('redirect', 1, PARAM_BOOL);